# Modeling a 4x4 Grid for Simple Game Using Looped ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, oop, user-interface

I am meant to create a game in Java that specifically uses looping Arraylists to create a 4x4 grid. I have a **Grid class**, made up of an ArrayList of 4 Rows, a **Row Class** made up of an ArrayList of Squares, and **Squares Class**. As well as other classes of objects, such as a hero and various enemies that will move to a random adjacent spot on the grid or "board" on each new turn.

I have methods in place to randomly assign starting positions, to find all possible adjacent positions and then select a random position out of those possible positions, etc.

The end product should look similar to this:

[image: Printed Grid]

Is a GUI necessary or is there a much more primitive, simple way to model to the user the 'Grid' with the objects in their current containers?

Comment: To answer your question, no, a GUI is not required, you could do this in the console/terminal with a monospaced font

Comment: No, a GUI is not necessary to create a model for the program, and in fact shouldn't be used. The model could be a simple 4x4 grid of logical (non-GUI) objects. The GUI is mainly  used to 1) display the state of the model and to 2) get input from the user.

Comment: You write that `I am meant to create a game in Java` - the only one who can answer **exactly** what you are meant to use to create that game is the one that asked you to create it! We may tell you that you *can* implement games without GUIs - but that cannot answer whether you *should*

Answer (score -1):

You can use `System.out.println("...")` to print out the info to the terminal. You can just put everything in a `String` and print it out. You'll be able to see each time you make a move and see previous moves and add in more verbose info if you want. Assuming your grid is in an `Arraylist grid`, the following code should help you see how it can work.

```java
for (Row row: grid){
    String str = "";
    for(Square square:row){
        str += square;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

You can use the [Java Scanner](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp) to grab input from the user instead of buttons.